# TypeError at /dj-rest-auth/google/ string indices must be integers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-socialauth, dj-rest-auth

I wanted to do social authentication using dj-rest-auth with google. But getting an error like this doesn't understand anything.

I want the advice of the experienced.

[image: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY]

[image: Submit Google Access token]

[image: Return Error]

I tried after submitting the access token it will return me a key for authentication.

But I can't get it because of the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved.
Only **django Vernson** Change to `django==4.0.8` to  `django==3.2.15`
this problem at `django==4.0.8`